# How do I prevent an ASP.NET MVC deployment on IIS 6.0, using wildcard mapping, from attempting to handle hidden share connections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

As noted by the title, what is the best way to configure an IIS 6.0 deployment of an ASP.NET MVC application such that connections to hidden shares are ignored? The application in question is using wildcard mapping to allow for clean URLs since we are planning on upgrading to IIS 7.0 in the near future and we are also handling the caching and compression issues with a custom library so we would like to avoid turning wildcard mapping off unless absolutely necessary.

Below is a one of the errors from the application to give you an example of what we are seeing.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
System.Web.HttpException
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time Stamp  - 03 Mar 2010, 08:11:44
Path        - N/A, Internal Server Operation
Message     - The controller for path '/C$' could not be found or it does not implement IController.
Target Site - System.Web.Mvc.IController GetControllerInstance(System.Type)
Stack Trace - 
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in the config

```
<location path="HiddenFolder">
  <system.web> 
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

And add ignore routes to your routes map:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("[HiddenFolder]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I assuming correct in that you have a hidden folder under your virtual directory?

If so, the hidden folder should still show up in IIS. You need to fake the folder as a virtual directory, which gives you access to the Configuration button and remove wild card mappings. Then Remove the folder as a virtual directory.

Comment: It's not a hidden folder under the virtual directory, it's the standard Windows administrative share that is apparently being accessed through Windows Explorer via \\server\c$